# как работать Telegram API update->edited_message на чистом PHP?

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telegram

Всем привет. я на питоне пользовал такой хендлер:

```
@bot.edited_message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
```

теперь хочу пользовать на чистом php. делаю так :

```
if (isset($updates->edited_message) && $updates->edited_message !=""){
.....
}
```

но не реагирует.
Как могу получить информации при редактировании сообщении?
не пользую никаких библиотеки.

Answer (score 0):

В telegram-bot-sdk это реализовано так:
$message = $this->update->getEditedMessage()
Может пригодится при решении задачи...